# Reacting to menu option selected without switch case

Tags: android, android-layout

So I made a fancy spinner menu with lots of options that really only need to change a single variable and then make a call to another function. Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        case R.id.optA:
            option = "a";
            fillContent(option);
            return true;
        case R.id.optB:
            option = "b";
            fillContent(option);
            return true;
        case R.id.optC:
            option = "c";
            fillContent(option);
            return true;
        case R.id.optD:
            option = "d";
            fillContent(option);
            return true;
}
```

Is there a more elegant (less switch cases/duplication) way of doing it? There's quite a lot more options and I don't want to duplicate code. I'm not using settings at the moment but I might in the future.

Is it possible to add some additonal XML tags for all menu options that I need so they can be identified by that?

Comment: Please, define `more elegant`.

Comment: Well, if there was an extra field in the XML that said which option it is (istead of the int from itemId) it could be filled by just checking if it has that field and then filling the option variable with that field.  Then it would be more elegant as there is less duplication and easier to read.

Comment: Your mind is obnubilated. There's no `more elegant` method than using a switch case. @LucasCrawford has shown you an **optimized** way of rewriting your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    case R.id.optA:
        option = "a";
        break;
    case R.id.optB:
        option = "b";
        break;
    case R.id.optC:
        option = "c";
        break;
    case R.id.optD:
        option = "d";
        break; 
}

fillContent(option);
return true;
```

I mean it can't really get anymore elegant than that, it really comes down to readability at this point for you and anyone else you work on this with.

Comment: This is a pretty good improvement

Comment: it removes duplication of code, so it's easier to read. But, i'd like to point out it wouldn't be that great anymore if you used additional settings. In which case, you would need to revert back, or have a conditional checking if option is not empty / not null

Comment: Why don't you give ASCII code char as menu item id and just call `fillContent(idAsChar)` this will cut the switch case :)

Comment: I don't think I can just pick an int myself for the id, AFAIK it has to be 

android:id="@+id/categoryA"